# Delete nth xelement from xdocument c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I have xml like below. I want to delete nth product node from that xml.

I had tried this but not working.

```
document.Descendants("products").Descendants("product").Take(1)
```

**XML**

```
<products>
    <product>
        <territory>A</territory>
    </product>
    <product>
        <territory>B</territory>
    </product>
    <product>
        <territory>C</territory>
    </product>
    <product>
        <territory>D</territory>
    </product>
    <product>
        <territory>E</territory>
    </product>
</products>
```

How to delete 3rd product node from this xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Linq` to `Xml`. You could use `ElementAt` and find an element at a given position, one could call `Remove` on a find element to remove the element.

```
    int position = 3;  // Specify position.
    XElement element = XElement.Parse(input);

    element                                      
        .Elements("product")
        .ElementAt(3)
        .Remove();
```

**Ouput**

```
 <products>
  <product>
    <territory>A</territory>
  </product>
  <product>
    <territory>B</territory>
  </product>
  <product>
    <territory>C</territory>
  </product>
  <product>
    <territory>E</territory>
  </product>
</products>
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5fr815)

Comment: thanks, Hari. suppose i want to remove all elements inside 2nd product node but not to delete product node then, how to implement it?

Comment: You could simply look for `.Elements.Remove()`, it remove elements not the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access child nodes by using an index. One way would be:

```
document.Descendants("products").Descendants("product").Skip(2).Take(1);
```